# How can i change menu color or submenu color in sugarcrm 6.5.0 RC1 CE?

Tags: colors, sugarcrm

How can i change menu color or submenu color in sugarcrm 6.5.0 RC1 CE ?

I am changing in themes/Sugar5/css/style.css file but it is being not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Place your CSS modifications in `custom/themes/default/css/style.css` and ensure you run a Repair & Rebuild once your code is in place. Make sure the file and all dirs leading to it have appropriate permissions.

If it's not working after that, use Chrome's developer tools to see if your CSS is properly loading at all and see how it's affecting the elements you're working on.

Comment: If you open it in firebug our similar tool, can you tell if the file is loading at all?

Answer (score 0):

See the **themedef.php** file in the theme folder. You need to make the colour changes in this file.

However, first turn the developer mode on from Admin>Settings to avoid the cache issue.